# Async POST request inside angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http

Making an Async post request inside .forEach is causing me a lot of problems. With or without the use of $resource I will get data lose. Or maybe the server just can't get all the requests processed at the same time, I don't really know.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
   // WHEN THE PROBLEM STARTS
angular.forEach($scope.item, function(item, i){
    var thisItemInv = {
        "title": $scope.item[i].title,
        "host_id": status.id;
    };
    // POST REQUEST
    $Http..
    or the same result with
    $resource
});
```

I can get just one result right, and the rest is incomplete. I get around this using jquery ajax with async to false, but I would like to avoid jquery and fix this the angular way

Comment: Are you watching the chrome networking tab or firebug, or some other network proxy to see what is happening with the requests?

Comment: @shaunhusain yes I do, and the request are completed and I get a response for all of them. But the result is incomplete. Only when using async to false on jquery I get it right

Comment: Please post your complete `$http` or `$resource` calls.  It sounds more like a scoping issue or possibly how you're handling the responses.  For a sanity check, I make plenty of parallel async ajax calls using angular without an issue.  I'd encourage you to look into `$q.all()` if you're waiting for them to all complete.